# What is the natural Lie groupoid structure on the Atiyah Lie groupoid of a principal $G$-bundle?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, connections, principal-bundles, lie-groupoids

$\DeclareMathOperator\At{At}\DeclareMathOperator\Obj{Obj}\DeclareMathOperator\Mor{Mor}$According to https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Atiyah+Lie+groupoid#idea the *Atiyah Lie groupoid* $\At(P)$ of a principal $G$ bundle $\pi:P \rightarrow X$ is a category for which $$\Obj(\At(P))=\lbrace \pi^{-1}(x): x \in X \rbrace$$ and $$\Mor(\At(P))=\big\lbrace f:\pi^{-1}(x)\rightarrow \pi^{-1}(y): \text{$f$ is a $G$ equivariant morphism}\big\rbrace.$$ Structure maps of this category are easy to guess. Now it is easy to see that $\At(P)$ is indeed a groupoid.

Although it is mentioned in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Atiyah+Lie+groupoid#idea that the *Atiyah Lie groupoid* is indeed a Lie groupoid, I am not able to guess  appropriate smooth structures on $\Obj(\At(P))$ and $\Mor(\At(P))$ such that the source and the target maps are surjective submersions and other structure maps are smooth.

Is there any **natural choice** of such smooth structures on both $\Obj(\At(P))$ and $\Mor(\At(P))$ such that $At(P)$ is a Lie groupoid so that if someone talks about the *Atiyah Lie groupoid* of a principal $G$ bundle then he/she is precisely assuming **those natural choice of smooth  structures** on $\Obj(\At(P))$ and $\Mor(\At(P))$?

I would  also be very grateful if someone point me to any literature in this direction.

Comment: At least according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah_algebroid), the obvious place to start with the literature is [Atiyah - Complex analytic connections in fibre bundles](https://doi.org/10.1090%2Fs0002-9947-1957-0086359-5).  Also, your definitions don't seem to match the [nLab's](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Atiyah+Lie+groupoid#over_the_pair_groupoid), which declares $X$ the objects and $(P \times P)/G$ the morphisms, both with obvious smooth structure. (Iincidentally, note if desired you can replace `\lbrace\rbrace` by `\{\}`.)

Comment: @LSpice Sorry if I sound stupid but I asked about Atiyah Lie Groupoids not Atiyah algebroid. According to wikipedia reference Atiyah Lie Algeroid is the Lie Algebroid of a Gauge Groupoid of a Principal bundle. How from this I can guess the smooth structure on $Obj(At(P))$  and $MorAt(P)$? Can you  please explain a bit in little detail?

Comment: @LSpice I was asking about the definition given in the section idea https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Atiyah+Lie+groupoid#idea not https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Atiyah+Lie+groupoid#over_the_pair_groupoid. So are you saying both are actually same notion and the definition given in the idea section is just an informal notion?

Comment: Yes, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366741/what-is-the-natural-lie-groupoid-structure-on-the-atiyah-lie-groupoid-of-a-princ#comment926383_366741) is what I am saying.

Comment: (Also, you don't sound stupid; quite possibly my reference to Atiyah's paper is stupid.  It's just that, if I'm looking for the literature on a concept with someone's name attached to it, I always start by looking at whether that person defined it and, if so, where.  I haven't met this concept, so went to Wikipedia to see where Atiyah had defined it.)

Comment: @LSpice But even if those 2 notions are same I cannot immediately see how they are same. For the definition given in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Atiyah+Lie+groupoid#over_the_pair_groupoid the smooth structure on Objects and morphisms are clear but from here how can I guess the smooth structures for the definition given in the "Idea" section https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Atiyah+Lie+groupoid#idea

Comment: There is no definition in the 'idea' section; it is just an idea, and, as not rigorously defined, cannot be checked against a rigorous definition.

Comment: @LSpice Ok I got your point. Thanks.

Comment: The objects as defined on the nLab and on Wikipedia give isomorphic sets. That the morphism sets are the same is less obvious, but it boils down to knowing that a map between principal homogeneous $G$-spaces is determined entirely by its value at a single point. It's worth thinking about the case of a trivialisable bundle first.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to what is claimed in the comments, I would argue
that the definition given in nLab's Idea section is rigorous
enough to be an actual definition in a research-level paper,
possibly with an additional phrase thrown in like
“The sets of objects and morphisms are equipped with the obvious
smooth structures that turn this groupoid into a Lie groupoid.”

Let's see how these smooth structures are constructed.
Recall that the set of objects is $\{π^{−1}(x)\mid x∈X\}$,
i.e., the set of fibers of $P$.
Fibers are in a bijective correspondence with points in the base $X$,
and the latter is a smooth manifold.

The set of morphisms is $\{f\colon π^{−1}(x)→π^{−1}(y)\mid \text{$f$ is a $G$-equivariant morphism}\}$.
A morphism between two $G$-torsors $U→V$ is uniquely determined
by its value $v∈V$ at some point $u∈U$.
That is, for any pair $(u,v)∈U⨯V$ there is exactly one morphism
that sends $u↦v$.
The pair $(gu,gv)$ gives rise to the same morphism $U→V$ as $(u,v)$.
It is also easy to see that the converse is true:
$(u,v)$ and $(u',v')$ yield the same morphism if there is $g∈G$ such
that $(u',v')=(gu,gv)$.
Thus, the set of morphisms $U→V$ is $(U⨯V)/G$,
where $G$ acts on $U⨯V$ via $g(u,v)=(gu,gv)$.
The action of $G$ on $U⨯V$ is a smooth free proper action,
so the quotient $(U⨯V)/G$ is a smooth manifold
and the quotient map $U⨯V→(U⨯V)/G$ is a submersion.

From here, we see that the set of all morphisms
is $(P⨯P)/G$ and therefore possesses a canonical smooth structure.
The source and target maps are surjective submersions by the 2-out-of-3 property.

Comment: Thank you Sir very much for the answer!

Comment: Calling a fibre $X$ if the base is already called $X$ is a bit awkward. I suggest to pick different letters in the middle paragraph, maybe $F_x$ and $F_y$.